# I can't convert the Pandas Dataframe type to datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, types, keyerror

I am pretty sure I should do like:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

But is keep getting the ERROR: "KeyError: 'date'" 
The data frame looks like this:

```
﻿         date       value
0  2004-01-01       0.265
1  2004-01-02       0.440
2  2004-01-05      -0.955
3  2004-01-06      -1.892
```

Comment: check if there are whitespaces or `\t` in your column name

Comment: Can't reproduce, can you show how the dataframe is being created?

Comment: What is `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50415981/edit) your question with the output of `df.head().to_dict()`, we may be able to quickly pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Do `df.columns = [x.strip() for x in list(df.columns)]` and then try your code.

Comment: output of df.head().to_dict() is    {'value': {0: 0.26500000000000001, 1: 0.44, 2: -0.95499999999999996, 3: -1.8919999999999999, 4: -2.597}, '\ufeffdate': {0: '2004-01-01', 1: '2004-01-02', 2: '2004-01-05', 3: '2004-01-06', 4: '2004-01-07'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The problem arises when you save the .csv in CSV UTF-8.

Comment: Why have you not posted the solution and only the problem?